# Is there a way to name an Apple Pencil on the iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-pencil

On the 2018 seamless design (matte finish / no lightning connector) Apple Pencil with the 2018 iPad Pro (USB C charger) I'm not seeing a way to give a name to the Apple Pencil that shows when I charge it.

Is there a setting that lets you name the pencil similar to on macOS where you can name bluetooth accessories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS 12.1.1 and lower, there is no way to name pencils if you have more than one or just wish to see a different name when it connects or looking at the battery levels.

- You can open settings app and see the serial number of the paired pencil if you tap in General and look towards the bottom of the data. Tap Apple Pencil and you can see details.
- You can't edit the name in the bluetooth settings - but the name there does match what's shown elsewhere "Apple Pencil" in English.